# Full /dev/sda3 partition on server

Tags: command-line, ssh

I am a super beginner with ssh and the command line and I need to get our website server back online. It has crashed because our /dev/sda3 partition is full.

Need help accessing that area so that I can see the logs and delete some to make space.

I have already tried to 'cd' to the folder and it cannot find this location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `cd` to `/dev/`. Instead, you go to the folder where `/dev/sda3` is mounted, which is probably a subfolder of `/mnt/`. From there, you can use `rm` to delete files.

I suggest you search the web for basic linux commands.